# PHP login issue wrong parameter given

Tags: php, mysql, parameters

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="";
$db_name="project";
$tbl_name="admin"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql='SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  `adminuser`="'.mysql_escape_string($myusername).'"AND `admin_pass`="'.mysql_escape_string(md5($mypassword)).'"';

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter '1' to be resource, Boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\login\check.php on line 27

I can't figure out what's wrong. Please help!

```
    if($count>=1){
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword"); 
        header("login/loginsuccess.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's your problem? What did you try? It will be useful to clarify your problem.

Comment: I tried to change the select query but the same error "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" appears.

Answer (score 1):

This string:

```
'SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  `adminuser`="'
```

...is in single quotes, which means that substring `$tbl_name` is **not** filled with contents of `$tbl_name` variable. Try this instead:

```
'SELECT * FROM ' . $tbl_name . ' WHERE  `adminuser`="'
```